# Tablesorter filter works, but from second attempt

Tags: jquery, filter, tablesorter

I'm using `jQuery tablesorter` (last version) and having an interesting issue with filter widget. It works, but only from second attempt. First time when i filter any column it does not filtering at all, but if i clear filter field (`backscape or delete`) and print something again it work just fine (Until i reload the page of course). Debug not showing any signs of problem.

Any thoughts?

Comment: An example of the table data and initialization code may clear things up. Please [modify this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/bbxxomhx/).

Answer (score 1):

Issue was solved by updating `jQuery` library to latest version.